# Show iterations for work item in TFS

Tags: tfs

I made a mistake in Team Foundation Server 2013 when trying to clean up our iterations. Our iteration path set up for the longest time was:

```
TFS PROJECT
    Sprint 1
    Sprint 2
    ...
```

There were discussions within the team, so I changed the Iteration path set up to this:

```
TFS PROJECT
    Iteration Group
        Sprint 1
        Sprint 2
        ...
    Readied Work
```

Well, after experimenting, I decided to move all the sprints under their parent `Iteration Group` back to the main `TFS PROJECT` parent. Unfortunately (this is where the mistake occurred), I deleted the `Iteration Group` container, thinking the Iterations would be re-parented. In doing so, all the child iterations were deleted and the work items that had been previously associated with each sprint were reallocated to the top parent, `TFS PROJECT`. The iteration path structure now looks like this:

```
TFS PROJECT
    Readied Work
```

I have already recreated the iterations, as we did not have a backup of the project/collection to which I could have rolled back. The DBA team is hands off the TFS database, so they are not available to assist. I know how Areas/Teams/etc work in TFS, but I am not familiar with the database structure.

---

**Given that I am able to see all the work items on the TFS portal, is there a way to show all IterationIDs each Product Backlog Item has been associated with, in a list?**

I would prefer to NOT look at the history of each PBI, as there are a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you only has a few iterations could use the 'was ever' operator. If you create a query and add a filter of IterationPath was ever '/project/group/iteration 1' you will see the work items that were ever under that node. You can then bulk edit everything you find under the desired path..

Comment: This is what I ended up using.

Answer (score 3):

First, I'd strongly recommend against touching the SQL database directly.

Using the TFS API you can [query work items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130306.aspx), and you can use the 'AsOf' operator to get the state from a historical point in time. Using this it wouldn't take much work to query the area/iteration paths of all your work items from 2 days ago, and then write them back to the current work items.