# TFS how to restore deleted Iteration data

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfsbuild, scrum

I incidentally deleted Iteration from TFS. Now, my all sprint tasks are moved to backlogs.

Is there a way to restore them?

Or I've to create sprint again and assign tasks to each individual sprint.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you delete an iteration node, the system automatically updates the existing work items with the node that you enter at the deletion prompt.

> You have chosen to delete this path. If you delete it, any work items,
>   tests, or other items in the team project that reference this path or
>   any of its dependent paths will be reassigned.

There is no way to restore the deleted iteration data, you have to create sprint again and assign tasks to each individual sprint.

Comment: Is there a way to find the start and end date of deleted sprints?

Comment: can we get task, bug, pbi from deleted sprint?

Comment: @Saadi `You have chosen to delete this path. If you delete it, any work items, tests, or other items in the team project that reference this path or any of its dependent paths will be reassigned.` The work items will be reassigned.You could not get task, bug ,pbi from deleted sprint.

Comment: @Saadi Afraid not. A workaround is roll your collection database (if you have backup), another solution is as Jason Williams suggested: Using the TFS API you can query work items, and you can use the 'AsOf' operator to get the state from a historical point in time. `Using this it wouldn't take much work to query the area/iteration paths of all your work items from 2 days ago, and then write them back to the current work items.` in this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25896014/show-iterations-for-work-item-in-tfs